# How to achieve Drag and drop feature in android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am making an app in which a list of different images will be shown at the bottom. From that list the user will be able to drag the images and drop it anywhere on the screen. After the dropp event the user will also be able to click this dropped image to it in fullscreen in new activity.

Now the problem is that somehow I have achieved all this but with some serious issues.
1) I am using framelayout where the imageviews will be dropped. So to place these dropped imageviews I am playing with their padding. And you all know that framelayout takes all views from top and left of the screen. I was searching for margins but unfortunately I didn't find anything like this.

So my question is: is there a good solution to my problem and should I continue using padding and framelayout or go for something else?

For my task, Absolute layout working is ideal but unfortunately this layout is depreciated.
SO please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html

Comment: http://androidrox.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/android-sample-app-drag-and-drop-image-using-touch/

Answer (score 0):

use "DragFramelayout" for creating Drag and Drop feature.
You can  refer android studio sample project for drag and drop feature.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ElevationDrag/